# where in rails with more of two params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I want my system to return a hierarchical set defined by a variable, I created this connection, however this system has a pagination of 15 in 15 elements per page, which turns sets into a larger set if I affirm That an element with id == 21 has the highest order would be for it to appear at the beginning, before all else, but only appears on the page where it was initially.
Here my controller.

```html
@services = Service.where(active: true).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

To increase the question the elements must obey the attributes: active? And if it is highlighted.

I would like to know how do I, a 'where', to maintain pagination but that I can hierarchically sort all elements of the total set.

For example:

in my set have 125 elements, theys organized in 15 by elements in paginations:

in Home have 15 elements, second page 15 lements, tird page 15 elements ...
They all are in factor hierarquical.
When i change this factor to great the element's position change too to great. If elment be in 7ª page and i change your factor hierarquical to great so your page go to great in firt page.

Comment: What do you want to sort the records on?  Or are you saying that you want the first page displayed to be page `2` if page '2' is the one that contains record with id `21`?

Comment: I want who first page show all elements, they have sorted in 15 by elements. This ordering must respect a hierarchical order. That id = 21 are related a example, if i select element with id == 21 like order great hierarquical so he have be in fist page.

Comment: Please rewrite the question to to include an example of the data and the desired result. As is it very difficult to understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I edit, I hope to be succinct!